# Where is the set default launch configuration option for a project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) and I want to have the "Run" command always launch the same configuration, but instead I always get a dialog box that asks me to choose which way to run my project.  How can I set a default?

Shouldn't matter, but this is for some Android development, so it's an Android project.

Comment: your asking the same question as [this][1] thread
cheers


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078733/how-to-create-default-debug-and-run-configuration-in-eclipse

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do the following;

- From the drop down menu select *Window* -> *Preferences*
- Then from the Categories on the right side; *Run/Debug* -> *Launching*
- Find a group box called "Launch Operation" at the bottom. If you change this to "Always launch the previously launched application" the <kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> shortcuts will debug/run whatever you debugged/ran before.

I don't understand why they changed the default behaviour for Eclipse 3.5, it is certainly one of the options I always change.

Comment: You just saved me from the most frustrating experience, sir! Spring Tool Suite suddenly started to pop up “Run on server...” dialog, even though I explicitly defined only *one* launch configuration and that is *not* using any servers, it's a stand-alone Spring Boot app. This magic fixed that for me.