# Make Eclipse debug a default project instead of current

Tags: eclipse

I'm currently working with a multi-platform project, where you have a main common library and several different platform setups (-android, -windows, -mac).

When I click debug while editing a library class, Eclipse asks me for a main class to launch, when it really cannot execute anything. I would like to change the behavior so when I start debugging while in a library class, any of the other projects will be the one launched by default.

As far as I have seen, Eclipse allows multilaunch, command parameters and favorites, but never default to other projects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create default debug and run configuration in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078733/how-to-create-default-debug-and-run-configuration-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can set Eclipse to always launch the previous launch by default.  Go to Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching and select "Always launch the previous application".

Comment: Thanks! Can you flag this as a duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078733/how-to-create-default-debug-and-run-configuration-in-eclipse ??